# Error in Asynctask during data fetching from mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, select, android-asynctask

Hi as i have used Asynctask in activity class during fetching data from mysql. But it is showing error still can you see and help me what i did wrong ?
I have checked connectivity issues they are fine, but i think error in code .I am not experienced of using android development please HELP !!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Day extends Activity {

    String dt="";
    String mc="";
    String bc="";
    ImageView dateimg;
    String name;
    String date;
    String targetmonth;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.day_lay);
        getCurrDate();
        new LongOperation().execute();
        dateimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);



        dateimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
                public void onClick(View v)
                 {  
                    //getCurrDate();

                    }

        });



    }


    public String getCurrDate()
    {

        Date cal = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        dt = cal.toLocaleString();

        mc = dt.substring(0, dt.length() - 17);
        bc=mc.substring(4);
        System.out.println("Date is"+bc);
        date=bc;
        return dt;

    }
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Day.this, ""," Can you just see your roof...");  
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_id);
            txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
            // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
            // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",date));

                try
                {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.1.2/wp-content/themes/app/day.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
                catch(Exception e)
            {
                    Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }     

                try
                {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                        is.close();
                        result = sb.toString();
                    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
                    System.out.println("Mainu pata hai"+result);
            }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }     

            try
                {
                    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                    targetmonth=(json_data.getString("targetmonth"));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : "+targetmonth,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //System.out.println("Mainu pata hai"+name);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                }

            return null;
        }




    }

}
```

// Database select

```
<?php
    $host='127.0.0.1';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='password';
    $db="android";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $date=$_REQUEST['date'];

    $r=mysql_query("select mat from vicks where date='$date'",$con);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $flag[name]=$row[name];
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

//Logcat

```
05-24 20:41:48.173: I/System.out(691): Date is24
05-24 20:42:01.749: E/pass 1(691): connection success 
05-24 20:42:01.969: E/pass 2(691): connection success 
05-24 20:42:01.969: I/System.out(691): Mainu pata hai{"name":"ollow the rhythm of your heart and you'll find out where your going"}
05-24 20:42:02.438: E/Fail 3(691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-24 20:42:02.438: D/AndroidRuntime(691): Shutting down VM
05-24 20:42:02.438: W/dalvikvm(691): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.status.what.Day$LongOperation.onPostExecute(Day.java:93)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.status.what.Day$LongOperation.onPostExecute(Day.java:1)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-24 20:42:02.498: E/AndroidRuntime(691):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is targetmonth equivalent in your JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have seen your webservice code. you are not passing "targetmonth" as key in your json. you are creating key as "name" in json on php side. so in android side instead of accessing targetmonth access the "name"

for exact answer please provide your json value you get from the webservices

Comment: ok let me clear 
i am fetching column name targetmonth from mysql
and query is select targetmonth from vicks where date='$date'
and date variable is sent from android

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $flag[name]=$row[name];
    }

in this $flag array you are creating key name ? please pass it between double quotes
and then access the name in jsonobject on android

Comment: is your webservice live ? can you give me url to check the response from the webservices

Comment: ya my webservice is live , i have checked it

Comment: can you give me url ? i'll create demo for you

Comment: i have seen this tutorial
http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php#Select Values from MySQL Database to Android

and rather than taking values from edittext i am taking value from string date funcion name

and finally implemented in asynctask and giving me error

Comment: as per your code "Mainu pata hai{"name":null}" this is your result . you have have to access "name" key in json and its value is null return from the php service so try this code in your php service  $flag[name]=$row[mat];

Comment: Megha Megha UR Right now its fetching But still giving me error on mylogcat . Can you see it and tell me Please :)

05-24 17:29:45.907: I/System.out(1855): Mainu pata hai{"name":"ollow the rhythm of your heart and you'll find out where your going"}
05-24 17:29:45.937: E/Fail 3(1855): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: i have updated my logcat, you can check the code under logcat

Comment: you fixed my data fetching problem thanks for that and i'll try to fix remaining problem in my code Thanks Megha

Answer (score 0):

you want to get `targetmonth` in android  code which is not in your JSON file
Please check this line

```
  targetmonth=(json_data.getString("targetmonth"));
```

Comment: I have set json_data.getString("name") instead of json_data.getString("targetmonth") but still give me error and data is not even getting from server

Comment: What data you are getting in respone from server?

Comment: i just want to fetch text data from mysql simply by following query mentioned in php   select mat from vicks where date='$date'

Answer (score 0):

The Jsonfield for targetMonth is null and you are using this null value in your code at

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : "+targetmonth,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: i have set json_data.getString("name")
instead of json_data.getString("targetmonth")  
but still give me error and data is not even getting from server